# Move only x-names closer to axis in boxplot

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

Have been reviewing various posts and sites, but I can't quite get this one right. I would like to move the x-names ("A", "B", etc) closer to the bars without moving the y-values on the left. I'm currently trying margins, but that seems to affect both x and y. I am missing something here.

```
par(mgp=c(0, 0.6, 0))
barplot(m1$Column, names.arg=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), col=rgb(0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 1), 
        main="MyTitle", 
        las=1, 
        cex.axis=0.7, 
        cex.names=0.7, 
        cex.main=0.7
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit `xaxt=`. Rebuild labels using `mtext` and control distance with the `line=` argument.

```
x <- setNames(1:5, LETTERS[1:5])
b <- barplot(x, xaxt="n", col=4)
mtext(names(x), side=1, line=.25, at=b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!